# Is it really so easy to fix Devel::ptkdb to support lvalue sub's? (rfce)

Tags: perl

I have to use a Perl Lib that use lvalue subs. For debugging I use since years Devel::ptkdb.

While debugging the Devel::ptkdb `die` with the message:

> can't modify non-lvalue subroutine call

So I start to investigate that problem and for now the resolution is add following sub to Devel::ptkdb (v1.1091):

```perl
sub lsub :lvalue {
  local $DB::single = 0;

  no strict;
  return &$DB::sub;
}
```

I also learned that my knowledge about TK and the Perl debugger internals are not deep enough to prove that this change does not have side effects so this is a request for code evaluation.

Comment: You can also try mentioning this to the [bug tracker](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Devel-ptkdb).

Comment: @choroba: Good point, it is now on [Sourcforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/ptkdb/support-requests/5/)

Comment: This is a bug report, or a request for code evaluation, or ... Well, I'm not sure what it is, but it isn't a question that's answerable in its current state. Please fix.